# How to fire the TStringGrid SelectCell event programmatically

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-10.4-sydney

I have tried some tips on how to do it, even a Team B code I've found using Grid->Row and Grid->Col, these properties are set, the SelectCell event is not fired though. It only works when I click on a cell with the mouse. Can someone help me on this task?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hmm ... I couldn't reproduce it. `OnSelectCell` is fired for me whenever I assign a new value to `Row` or `Col`. Assigning the same value as it already has does however _not_ fire the event.

Comment: I will try changing cells, selecting the second and then the first.

Comment: Thank you very much @TedLyngmo, setting Grid->Col to 1 and swiching from Grid-Row = 2 to Grid->Row = 1 did the trick.